# Removing unwanted vertical space at end of post resulting from pile-up of negative positioning of <div> elements

Tags: html, css, whitespace

In [this blog post of mine](http://michelegorini.blogspot.it/2017/06/cartello-stradale-di-luce-lunare_27.html), I needed many two-column bits, and that resulted in many  elements. That caused lots of unwanted vertical space between them. I googled, and found out how to `position: relative; top: -<whatever number>px`. Now all the vertical space has piled up at the end. My googling did not reveal any command for negative vertical space (think LaTeX `\vspace` with negative argument), though that's what I was googling for. Is there any way to remove that huge space at the end?

PS I'm a total noob when it comes to web page design: all I know is a little HTML which I figured out by looking at the HTML for my other blog posts or which I googled for, and that little bit of CSS for the padding of tables. I do not know if Blogger accepts anything but pure HTML+CSS.

**Update**

Problem solved with CBroe's comment. Blog post originally ended like this:[image]

Comment: Relative positioning only moves an element in regard to its “default” position, but preserves the original space required by the element. If you want to “move” elements without that effect, use `margin` instead.

Comment: @CBroe problem solved. Would accept that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Relative positioning only moves an element in regard to its “default” position (that it would have in normal flow, if the element was not positioned at all), but preserves the original space required by the element.

If you want to “move” elements without that effect, you can use for example `margin` instead.